# What does 'in looping script' mean

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Her attention was drawn to ranks of black-and-white photographs in silver frames, hunters wearing shooting caps posed with strings of birds or piles of game, several of women in saris, their hair piled high in the style of the ﬁfties, one in riding breeches, with an oversized dedication **in looping script**.

Comment: Please remember to give the source of quotations you ask about! You have been told about this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase *looping script* means ornate handwriting. The pictures have handwritten dedications in an elaborate style.

A search for the phrase *looping script handwriting* brought up some examples of printing fonts that imitate looping handwriting:

[Etsy *looping script font*](https://www.etsy.com/no-en/market/looping_script_font)

[1001 Fonts *loopy, cursive fonts*](https://www.1001fonts.com/loopy+cursive-fonts.html)